# ExtJS: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of undefined

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, scope, viewcontroller

I've created a panel through this [sample](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#form-contact) and it has 2 items under `tools` config. Both items have their own function which binds through `ViewController`. The `refresh` item's function is working pretty well but the `gear` item's function gives this error below;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of undefined
    at constructor.addListener (Observable.js?_dc=1516015518102:1135)
    at constructor (Observable.js?_dc=1516015518102:403)
    at constructor.beforeInitConfig (Component.js?_dc=1516015518101:2261)
    at Ext.Configurator.configure (Configurator.js?_dc=1516015518102:558)
    at constructor.initConfig (Base.js?_dc=1516015518101:1554)
    at constructor (Component.js?_dc=1516015518101:2137)
    at new constructor (Class.js?_dc=1516015518101:42)
    at Object.widget (ClassManager.js?_dc=1516015518101:1638)
    at constructor.create (ComponentManager.js?_dc=1516015518102:76)
    at constructor.lookupComponent (Container.js?_dc=1516015518101:1564)
```

I've moved the view class from `app` folder to `classic` folder but `ViewController` class stays in `app` folder so I guess that error is raising up through `this` notation. How should I declare it within ViewController?

```
weatherWindow: function () {
        var win = this.lookupReference('weatherWindow');

        if (!win) {
            win = new MyApp.view.weather.SettingsWindow();
            this.getView().add(win);
        }

        win.show();
    },
```

---

**UPDATE**
I've created a `ViewController` for the view but still gives `scope` error!

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.dash.WeatherView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'weatherview',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.dash.WeatherViewVC',

    ],

    controller: 'weatherView',

//and..
Ext.define('MyApp.view.dash.WeatherViewVC', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.weatherView',

    requires: [],

    weatherWindow: function () {
        debugger;

        var win = this.lookupReference('settingsWindow');

        if (!win) {
            win = new MyApp.view.weather.SettingsWindow();
            this.getView().add(win);
        }

        win.show();
    },
```

Comment: i've moved all files under `weather` folder but still gives `scope` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this error. Created a function within window class and return it;

```
getSettingsItems: function () {
    var me = this;

    var settingsItems = [
        // whole items listed here!
    ];

    return settingsItems;
},
```